# GCS_Clarke_1880 transformation to GCS_WGS_1984 in ArcGIS 10.3.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, coordinate-system

ArcGIS 10.3.1 has no transformation for GCS_Clarke_1880 to GCS_WGS_1984. Why is this the case, what have I missed?

***Do we have to write a custom transformation?***

There are a heap of Clarke transformation equations on stack. But I don't understand why.

**GCS_Clarke_1880 WKID: 4034 Authority: EPSG**

> Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433)  Prime Meridian: Greenwich
>   (0.0)  Datum: D_Clarke_1880    Spheroid: Clarke_1880
>        Semimajor Axis: 6378249.144808011
>        Semiminor Axis: 6356514.966204133
>        Inverse Flattening: 293.4663076556253

To

**GCS_WGS_1984 WKID: 4326 Authority: EPSG**

> Angular Unit: Degree (0.0174532925199433) Prime Meridian: Greenwich
>   (0.0) Datum: D_WGS_1984   Spheroid: WGS_1984
>       Semimajor Axis: 6378137.0
>       Semiminor Axis: 6356752.314245179
>       Inverse Flattening: 298.257223563

[image]

Comment: OP please read. Related, if not a duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88415/how-to-convert-from-one-ellipsoid-to-another

Comment: No, there aren't any Clarke 1880 transformations. There are heaps of GeoCRS (datum) transformations for GeoCRS that are based on Clarke 1880. What's the actual GeoCRS or datum for your data? What location does it represent?